# Play framework page navigation issues

Tags: html, playframework, navigation

I am having an issue with page navigation: When I am on a page such as `localhost:9000/data/userX/userhome`, and I click the home button on this page, it is going only to one level backward and trying to open `localhost:9000/data/userX/index`.

I have tried different route entries but didn't work.

Comment: Provide some more details.

Comment: How does the code for your homebutton/link look like?

Comment: Sofar I am using like this, <a href="index">Home</a>, In routes file "GET /index controllers.Application.index(), it is working fine if I am on the same level. If I go little deeper like <localhost>/data/userX/userhome, from this page if i click on the home button, it is trying to open "<localhost>/data/userx/index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your comment, try

```
<a href="/index">Home</a>
```